# "Variables should be given the smallest scope". Really?

Tags: .net, performance, loops, optimization, timer

I have read the following sentence a multiple times:

> Generally, variables should be given the smallest scope.

See the use of variable `num` in the following scenarios:

```
Private num As Integer
Private Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    'Your code where num is initialized and used
End Sub
```

Or:

```
Private Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
     Dim num As Integer
     'Your code where num is initialized and used
End Sub
```

Bare in mind that `Timer_Tick` is a looping timer, hence `num` in the the first scenario is declared only once while in the second scenario it is declared every time the timer ticks.

Is the first usage really different in terms of code execution speed? Which one is more efficient? In regards of these examples, to what extent is the quoted sentence correct neglecting the readability preference?

I believe that if there is a huge amount of iterations and looping in the code, the second scenario would have some performance effect over the first.

Comment: Yes, 2nd option is better. This is a computer science 101 thing. The course number was COMP 170 when I took it 18 years ago, and I can still remember my professor, Dr Baird, explaining it (though not the actual words or reasoning... just that it was the better option). But, in a nutshell, it allows memory to be collected faster, prevents accidentally leaking bad state, helps you avoid clutter in the namespace so important things stand out, put names and types closer to their use so they are easier to modify and reason about. I could go on.

Comment: @GrantWinney you are right but I'm not considering the readability issue over speed and performance.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn How can this be justified since the declaration is looping many many times in the `timer` while in the first scenario, it is done once only!

Comment: The compiler makes the difference disappear. Basically, the variable is put on the stack as part of the function call, so it costs effectively nothing. If you have more than a stack frame can hold, the compiler might "hoist" the variables to a single instance of a private class. There are many _many_ tricks it can use. But to paraphrase Ben Franklin, if you trade a little correctness for a little performance, you'll end up with neither.

Comment: Thank you @JoelCoehoorn. BTW, I liked the quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Generally, variables should be given the smallest scope.

I agree.

> Is the first usage really different in terms of code execution speed?

Not because of scope alone.

> Which one is more efficient?

If it was just a matter of scopes, then I would expect them to compile to very similar CIL, if not identical, and as such have no difference. There can be some minor quirks causing one to very slightly beat the other, but then such quirks can go either way.

In this case though the difference in scope means there is not a comparison of like with like; a field outside a method is not the same thing as a local within. Generally a field is more expensive to use than a local, though if the initialisation need happen only once and was itself expensive then that caching ("memoisation") could pay off. This isn't a difference of scope alone, however. Scope tends not to have an appreciable performance impact unless it is hiding something which also makes it not like-with-like (e.g. a captured local is not the same as a non-captured).

> In regards of these examples, to what extent is the quoted sentence correct neglecting the readability preference?

The quoted sentence is all about the readabilty and the fact that you know the scope of the variable's use from the scope of its allowed use. The tighter the scope the better it reflects the intention, which is what human-readable code should strive for.

> I believe that if there is a huge amount of iterations and looping in the code, the second scenario would have some performance effect over the first.

Only because it isn't just scope at play here, but type of variable also.